# Finding the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n\left[\log_2(n+1)-2\log_2 n-\log_2(\sin \frac{1}{n})\right]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

How could i find following limit.

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n\left[\log_2(n+1)-2\log_2 n-\log_2(\sin \frac{1}{n})\right]$.

I tried $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n \log_2\frac{(n+1)}{n^2\sin \frac{1}{n}}$ but i stuck.

Comment: do the $\log$'s really have different bases?

Comment: You need to say something about what you tried here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has $$n\log_2 \frac{n+1}{n^2sin(\frac 1n)}$$ Make $n=\frac1x$ so $x\to 0$ this becomes by continuity of $\log_2$ and the well known limit $\frac{x}{sin x}$

$$\frac 1x \log_2\frac{(1+x)x}{sin x}\to\frac1x\log_2(1+x)\to\log_2(1+x)^{\frac1x}\to\log_2 e$$
The answer is $\log_2 e$ where $e$ is the base of natural logaritms

Comment: Your proof has problems. What do the arrows mean? And getting rid of $x/\sin x$ is a bit suspicious without justification. Do you think $\lim_{x\to 0}(1/x^3)\ln [(1+x^3)(x/\sin x) ]= \lim_{x\to 0}(1/x^3)\ln (1+x^3)?$

Comment: @zhw., I agree.  (See my answer.)

Comment: convergence, obviously! which it is not so for those who do not want to see it. I have problems with Tex Commands however the deduction is correct.

Comment: @zhw:  place your "a bit suspicious" elsewhere,please.What do you think I am?  I have written "by continuity of $\log_2$ and the well known limit $\frac{x}{sinx}$" and this is enough to justify the given steps.Except for those who do not want to see it.

Comment: Come now, "suspicious" is just a play word. And simply knowing $x/\sin x \to 1$ is not enough. You can't just pretend it's $1.$ Apparently you did not read the end of my comment. Do you think $\lim_{x\to 0}(1/x^3)\ln [(1+x^3)(x/\sin x) ]= \lim_{x\to 0}(1/x^3)\ln (1+x^3)?$

Comment: I wanted the limit of $\log_2[(1+f(x))(\frac{x}{sinx})]^{\frac{1}{f(x)}}=\log_2[(1+f(x))^{\frac{1}{f(x)}}\cdot(\frac{x}{sinx})^{\frac{1}{f(x)}}]$ when $x\to 0$ and $f(x)\to 0$ where $f(x)=x$ not what you want. I could accept having committed a lack of explanation (because of my English and inexperience with Text Command) but not your "a bit suspicious". I cannot accept it: I once heard some time ago the great Laurent Schwartz say  “mathematics is a school of morality”.

Comment: @Ataulfo, as I explain in my answer, it is not enough to know that $x/\sin x\to1$ as $x\to0$.  You need to explain what it is about the well known limit that allows you to get rid of it.  That's what zhw. is getting at in his/her last comment:  If you think it's OK to replace $x/\sin x$ with $1$ in the OP's problem, do you think it's OK to do so as well in the limit zhw. poses? If not, then you need to explain why it's OK for the one problem but not for the other.

Comment: Then the donkey (I am) blow the flute by chance (famous fable of Thomas Iriarte). OK, Mr Cipra, OK. Cordially, good by.

Answer (score 5):

You can rewrite this as

$${1\over\ln2}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}n\ln\left(n+1\over n\right)+\lim_{n\to\infty}n\ln\left(1/n\over\sin(1/n) \right) \right)$$

As others have noted, the first limit is $1$, because $\left(1+{1\over n}\right)^n\to e$ as $n\to\infty$.  The second limit, however, has to be done a little bit carefully.  It's not enough to note that $(1/n)/\sin(1/n)\to1$ in order to conclude that $\ln1=0$ implies the limit is $0$; that same logic would imply the first limit is $0$ as well.

Letting $x=1/n$, the second limit can be rewritten as

$$\lim_{x\to0}{\ln x-\ln\sin x\over x}$$

L'Hopital says this should equal

$$\lim_{x\to0}\left({1\over x}-{\cos x\over\sin x}\right)=\lim_{x\to0}{\sin x-x\cos x\over x\sin x}$$

and L'Hopital again says *this* should equal

$$\lim_{x\to0}{x\sin x\over\sin x+x\cos x}=\lim_{x\to0}{\sin x\over{\sin x\over x}+\cos x}={0\over1+1}=0$$

Putting everything together, the desired limit is

$${1\over\ln2}(1+0)={1\over\ln2}$$

Comment: Piquito said the same thing, but you bashed him. What different you have done, I don't see.

Comment: @NimaBavari, I explained the difference in the comments below Piquito's answer.  (Note, Piquito must have gone by the username Ataulfo at the time.)

Answer (score 1):

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n\left[\log_2(n+1)-2\log_2 n-\log_2(\sin \frac{1}{n})\right]$.

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \log_2(\frac{(n+1)}{n^2\sin \frac{1}{n}})^n$

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \log_2(\frac{(1+1/n)}{(\frac{\sin \frac{1}{n}}{1/n})})^n$

when n goes to infinity $1/n$ goes to zero

then $(\frac{\sin \frac{1}{n}}{1/n})$ goes to $1$

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \log_2(\frac{(1+0)}{1})^n$

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \log_21^n$

when $n=1$, $1^n=1$

the answer is $0$

Answer (score 1):

So like Barry said we have:

$${1\over\log 2}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}n\log\left(n+1\over n\right)-\lim_{n\to\infty}n\log\left(\sin(1/n) \over 1/n \right) \right)$$

An alternative way of showing the second limit tends to $0$:

We will use the fact that $x - \dfrac {x^3} {3!}\le \sin x \le x$ for $x \ge 0$.

It follows that:

$$n \log \left(1 - \frac 1 {3! n^2} \right)\le n \log \left( \frac {\sin (1/n)} {1/n}\right) \le 0$$

If we can show the LHS tends to $0$ we have the desired result by squeeze/sandwhich theorem.

Well $$\lim_{n \to \infty} n \log \left(1 - \frac 1 {3! n^2} \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac 1 {3!n}\left[3!n^2 \log \left( 1 - \ \frac 1 {3! n^2} \right)\right] = -\frac 1 {3!} \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac 1 n=0$$

Answer (score 1):

We will use $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\color{#C00000}{\frac{\log(1+x)}x}=\color{#C00000}{1}$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\color{#00A000}{\frac{\sin(x)-x}{x^2}}=\color{#00A000}{0}$.
$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left[\log_2(n+1)-2\log_2(n)-\log\left(\sin\left(\tfrac1n\right)\right)\right]\\
&=\frac1{\log(2)}\lim_{n\to\infty}\color{#C00000}{\frac{\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)}{\frac1n}}
-\log_2\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\color{#00A000}{\frac{\sin\left(\frac1n\right)-\frac1n}{\frac1{n^2}}}\frac1n\right)^n\,\right]\\
&=\frac1{\log(2)}\cdot\color{#C00000}{1}-\log_2\left(e^{\color{#00A000}{0}}\right)\\[3pt]
&=\frac1{\log(2)}
\end{align}
$$